# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Core Plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot

I implemented the **core plot**  in my app & it works fine. But it  show the graph only first time. when i try it to see again, It shows me bad excess.

The problem is all the data in **CPDStockPriceStore.m** is call first time & try it see the graph again, then the breakpoint in **CPDStockPriceStore.m** are not come & it will direct shoe me **Bad_Excess in chartviewController**

**the line code where i am getting bad_excess :**

`NSInteger valueCount = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];`

I think there is a problem on sharedInsance. Is it so?

I don't know why this happen??

**Update**

I implemented the core plot in my app & it works fine. But it show the graph only first time. when i try it to see again, It shows me Graph with old Data.

The problem is all the data in `CPDStockPriceStore.m` is call first time & try it see the graph again, then the breakpoint in `CPDStockPriceStore.m` are not come

i have a table view & show graph with different data according to row selected. But now, The `CPDStockprice` file is not call more than ONE time. So, i can't able to show graph with different data. graph shows me with same data which i selected the row first. If i select new row then it shows me graph with previous data.

I don't know why this happen?? Help me!

Comment: Post full error messages by copy and and pasting, not by retyping a tiny part of the error message. You're demonstrating here the risk of retyping: it's BAD_ACCESS, not Bad_Excess.

Comment: Also, usually you'll want to post more code than just the one line where a problem manifested itself.

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't just obliterate your original question and make it into a new question. It means my answer is now obsolete and doesn't make sense for anyone else visiting this question. You should leave the original question but update it (add an 'update' section at the end) if you need to.

Comment: Ok, have reinstated the original question and added your changes as an update to the end.

Comment: In fact, for a change like this, you're better just asking a new question. Consider opening a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors (rather than Bad_Excess, which doesn't exist) if you try to dereference (i.e. access) a reference to an objective C object which has been deallocated.

In other words, it's a memory management issue. The problem is that the retain count for your object has reached 0, and the runtime has deallocated the object -- it's not there any more.

Are you using ARC in your project?

Comment: No, i am not using ARC & yes You are right, I am Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS & what code do you need

Comment: For example, where else do you interact with CPDStockPriceStore in your code?

Comment: yes, I solved the BAD_ACCESS using enable the arc for the chart view & CPDStockPriceStore. But i have a table view & show graph with different data according to row selected. But now, The CPDStockprice file is not call more than ONE time. So, i can't able to show graph with different data. graph shows me with same data which i selected the row first. If i select new row then it shows me graph with previous data.

Comment: the CPDStockPrice file's method is not called more than one time

Comment: It's not really feasible for me to debug your exact problems via stack overflow. But at least now you know why EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs and what it means. Please consider accepting my answer if you found it useful.